# SSIS imports NULL values from Excel?

Tags: excel, import, ssis

I am importing from Excel. It has to be Excel as there are multiple worksheets and I don't want to have to have multiple csv files.

One of the fields on the spreadsheet is called "number and name" a sample of what is stored in this field is 1,2,3,4,1a,G5.

As you can see it's a mix of numeric and text.

When I import from SSIS I do a data conversion as it doesn't like the fact that it unicode to non unicode - so I convert it to a string. It then NULLS and fields that have a mix of numeric and text but leaves the numeric in place?

Why would it do that and how do I get round it?

Comment: This is a very old yet frequent issue. Do a search on IMEX

Comment: Doesn't work - when I include that it nulls everything

Comment: This is the connection string -Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\Data Migration\Monmouthshire DataMigration\DataExtracts\DataExtract.xlsm;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 MACRO;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";

Comment: Have you tried this connection string with `HDR=NO`. I know this is not the normal way the connection string is coded for IMEX, but I've had a recent example file where this worked when `HDR=YES` did not!

Comment: Made no difference, the only way round it was to convert that column to TEXT in Excel. I can't get it to work any other way.